# NSBitmapImageRep resizing

Tags: objective-c, macos, image, bitmap, resize

Is there any ways to resize `NSBitmapImageRep`?

I found method `setPixel:atX:y:` but I'm not sure what it is doing. Maby it is what I need?

If no, then how can I do it?

I need to resize image before writing it to file, and my image comes in `NSBitmapImageRep`. Afcourse I can transform it to `NSImage` or `CIImage` if it would be easier to resize. If it is, then just let me know.

By the way, I need to have ability to resize image without maintaining any proportions. For example if image is `3200x2000`, I need to have ability to resize it to size `100x100`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an implementation which interpolates your source properly.

You can accomplish this using a `CGBitmapContext` of the destination size (e.g. 3200x3200) and specification, then drawing the source image image to the `CGBitmapContext`. Then you can either use the CGBitmapContext's image create function, or use the context's bitmap buffer for your output samples.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** You can resize image using below function without maintaining any proportions:

```
- (NSImage *)imageResize:(NSImage*)anImage
         newSize:(NSSize)newSize 
{
 NSImage *sourceImage = anImage;
 [sourceImage setScalesWhenResized:YES];

 // Report an error if the source isn't a valid image
 if (![sourceImage isValid])
 {
    NSLog(@"Invalid Image");
 } else
 {
    NSImage *smallImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: newSize] autorelease];
    [smallImage lockFocus];
    [sourceImage setSize: newSize];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
    [sourceImage compositeToPoint:NSZeroPoint operation:NSCompositeCopy];
    [smallImage unlockFocus];
    return smallImage;
 }
 return nil;
}
```

Secondly like this with maintaining proportions:

```
NSData *imageData = [yourImg  TIFFRepresentation]; // converting img into data
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData]; // converting into BitmapImageRep 
NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor]; // any number betwwen 0 to 1
imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps]; // use NSPNGFileType if needed
NSImage *resizedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData]; // image created from data
```

Comment: As I mentioned earlier `I need to have ability to resize image without maintaining proportions`, and I guess your suggested method maintains proportions.

Comment: It returns good size image, but image is empty. Where is the problem?